# Why is my database finding non-existent things in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
        public boolean find_uid(String uid){
          String [] columns = new String [] {DB_Helper.KEY_NAME};
          Cursor c = database.query(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE_USERS, columns,null,null,
             null,
             null,
             null);
           boolean value=   c.moveToFirst();
           c.close();
           //didn't find it

            if(!value)  {
        Log.d("value", "false");
        return false;   
             }
           //did find it
           else return true;

        }
```

The sting uid doesn't exist in the database. I know that for a fact. But query always returns a cursor such that c.moveToFirst() always returns true.

Why?

Comment: How do you know for a fact?  Believe me, SQLite does not "invent" values to return to you.

Comment: I want to delete this post but cannot. One of those nulls should not be a null. (the first one.)

Comment: @user678392 Feel free to edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the uid you pass into the method.. So all you are doing is querying for all records in that table.

Try adding a where clause to your query. Make sure you change DB_Helper.UID_COLUMN to whatever you actually have as your UID column name.

```
String where = DB_Helper.UID_COLUMN + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { uid };
Cursor c = database.query(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE_USERS, columns,where,whereArgs,
             null,
             null,
             null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't searching for uid-  you have no where clause, so you're selecting every row in the table.